# How to use function returnig dictionary in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I got something like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def status(self):
        return{'status':1, 'days':10}
```

and in the template

```
{{ mymodel.status['status'] }}
```

but it gives my `Could not parse the remainder: '['status']' from 'mymodel.status['status']'`

what is the best way to make it work?

Comment: Ok my bad I got `return{'status':1, 'days':int(days)` -days being timedelta. And that's why mymodel.status.days didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In django template, accesing the item `'item'` also use `.item` form.

So, use `.status`:

```
{{ mymodel.status.status }}
```

See [The Django template language - Variables - Behind the scenes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#variables).